# Force menu to stay in 1 line and force the page to have 1 page with no scroll

Tags: css, scroll, menu, nav

I want the main nav menu to be at 1 line on all screen not only big screens, and i want the home page to be 1 page static with no scroll only cover and footer.

This is the site: http://alaa.x10host.com

I have tried so many ways, like display flex and width 100% for container and for nav menu, but I tried alot and nothing works

`display:flex;`

`width:100%;`

`font-size: 1vw`

A full 1 static page no scroll and full menu on all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

As for the menu - add this line to your css

```
@media (min-width: 960px)
.row .primary-menu-ul>li {
width: inherit;
padding: 10px 0;
width: 20%;
```

This will tell all li elements that they cannot be more than 20% of their parent element and since you have 5 menu items they will always take 100%.

as for the scroll - you need to adjust ALL sizes related to paddings and margins from px to % / em and get rid of the min height css rules for inner container (I am referring to the one with background image). Like here:

```
.elementor-159 .elementor-element.elementor-element-1dd43d0 > .elementor-container {
/* min-height: 34vh; */
```

}

I commented out this rule. Also saw some paddings set up in px as well as font sizes. Main issue with this website that inner container is not 100% responsive that's why you may see vertical scroll on mobile devices.

Comment: Hi Man, 
i have done excatly what you tell me, 
please check the result, the menu seems to work bit i got the name into 2 lines 
can we fix that with a code for the <a>
big thanks man 
really thank you

Comment: and it seems like we are near for the cover setting ?

Comment: Your body in css has font size 16px, change it to percentages and then add this style as well for the menu: http://prntscr.com/omm3a5

Comment: i have this link for the same site, and only still strugle with the manu
http://alaab.myartsonline.com/

could you please check it ?
if its fixed then no need to the other one.
big thanks again

Comment: the fix you suggest for the menu, makes the fonts of the menu so small, and not near to each other, do you think there is another method to fix it ?

Comment: Well I have shown you the path colleague, the rest is up to you. As I understood you are using a ready made theme which is insane for a website with few blocks of text. As I shew in a screenshot above , the menu does work, the main content you will have to figure out yourself where to change which styles. As I said - check for the hardcoded px margins , paddings and fontsizes and change them to percentages.

Comment: Well, this is a common sense - you cannot fit 2 liter of water into 1 liter bottle. Font size is relational to the block it is inside (which is <li>) and <li> has 20% width and auto height. So to fit few words in one <li> they have to be really small.

Comment: at this web site for example, 
alaab.myartsonline.com

i used width 1vw with a full container width 100%
its works good and the size were changing according to screen size, 
but a friedn suggest that i should use menu flex but it seems like it doesnt work out 

do you think we can fix the menu at this site ?
alaab.myartsonline.com

Comment: cant we assign <li> and <li> to be bigger and make the logo area smaller ?

Comment: absolutely, if you need you can make logo smaller and thus area of <UL> will become bigger automatically. As for the flex - I don't see the reason why you need it here, seriously.

Comment: i dont really know why he used the flex on the menu, i just removed it now.

but i didnt catch what have u done in this prntscr.com/omn6o2
i notice that u made the width 100%, but it doesnt work

Comment: hey man, 
i fix it this way, but i think, its a noob fix, what do you think, it seems easier with the screen shot you sent before :) 


.site-branding.col-md-4.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 {
  width: 150px;
 left:30px;

}

#primary-menu.menu {
  position: relative;

}
#primary-menu.menu {
float:left;
  width: 69em;
}

@media (min-width: 925px) and (max-width: 1250px){.main-navigation a{font-size:86%;
 font-weight:600;}}


.site-header .container {
  width: 100%;
}

Comment: well as soon as it works - it works. In ideal variant I would say - rewrite it from scratch without using ready made themes =) And as I said - try to avoid hardcoded values (unless there are not for media queries and even then....)

Comment: its a wp site, and its hard to get an easy site to code there,
also iam not that good yet :)

please tell me what u used here at this screen shot, as it seems easier and cleaner :) https://prnt.sc/omn6o2

Comment: I see that you have already fixed the bug and now menu is always in one line position.